# How to deploy a Symfony2.1 local website to a remote server using capifony [Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed]?

Tags: symfony, deployment, capistrano, capifony

I have my Symfony2.1 website folder in /Sites/mywebsite and there is git in it.
I would like to use capifony to fast deploy my website to my remote server (I'm currently using ftp).
So I install capifony, and initiate capifony in my project using `capifony .`

I use the second solution as describing here http://capifony.org/ (deployment->production via copy), so I set up my deploy.rb file like this :

```
set :application, "mywebsite"
set :domain,      "199.178.832.3:8534"
set :deploy_to,   "git/mywebsite.git"
set :app_path,    "app"

set :repository,  "file:///Users/me/Sites/mywebsite"
set :scm,         :git
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `subversion`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, or `none`

set :model_manager, "doctrine"
# Or: `propel`

role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain                         # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,         domain, :primary => true       # This is where Symfony2 migrations will run

set :use_composer, true

set :use_sudo,      false
set :keep_releases,  3
set :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.yml"]
set :shared_children,   [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads", "vendor"]

set :deploy_via, :rsync_with_remote_cache
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
ssh_options[:keys] = ["~/.ssh/id_rsa"]

# Be more verbose by uncommenting the following line
logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
```

But when I run `cap deploy:setup`, I have the following error :

```
  * 2013-03-19 10:52:06 executing `deploy:setup'
  * executing "mkdir -p git/mywebsite.git git/mywebsite.git/releases git/mywebsite.git/shared"
    servers: ["199.178.832.3"]
Password: 
connection failed for: 199.178.832.3:8534 (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: me)
```

It asks for a password and I don't understand which one and why because I add my public key to my remote server in authorized_keys and I don't set a password for this public key.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you can connect via SSH yourself using that key and username `me`. If still the same problem, then enable more verbose output and enable [Pseudo Terminal](http://justinmaccarthy.org/?p=99):

```
ssh_options[:verbose] = :debug
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```